# Error in ofStream, Qt 5.14.2 can 't write string into file

Tags: c++, string, qt, mingw, ofstream

I am trying to write my program from VS (MVCS) for Qt(MinGb)
I am using ofstream and has a following code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
void WriteToFile(ofstream* fileToWrite, std::string StringNeedsToWrite)
{
    if (fileToWrite)
    {
        if (IsStartOfNewString(StringNeedsToWrite))
        {
            *fileToWrite << '\n';
        }
        *fileToWrite << StringNeedsToWrite;     
    }
    else
    {
        throw exception();
    }
}
```

I want to write string into file, and set ofstream into my method.
But i have a strange error and don't know how to fix it (on image)

[image: Error on image]

Comment: Did you try to pass into your method pointer of file and make stream inside your method?

Comment: @bogdyname Please use the English language which is the official language of SO.

Comment: @AndrewPilikin Please use the English language which is the official language of SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They differ in their make files and project files. A common problem is that moving a project from one environment to another entails big mistakes.
For example, **MinGW** under **Linux** does not have standard streams, but there is `windows.h`.

Such problems should be taken into account and studied at the stage of developing a program architecture and choosing technologies for development.

Frequent practice has shown that **Qt** is best used with your **IDE** and, if possible, use its classes for development.